# How to Crop ROI from large images with mouse using Open CV 3 python 3

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-3.6

I can successfully crop ROI from [small images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yxLX.png).
But when i try the same code for [large images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xid6l.jpg),the window couldn't open the full image because of the small resolution of screen.I have resized the image to fit to window but after cropping when i resized the cropped image its pixel values are changed.Is there any way with opencv that pixel values remain same.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
refPt = []
cropping = False        
def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):

    global refPt, cropping
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        refPt = [(x, y)]
        cropping = True
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPt.append((x, y))
        cropping = False
        cv2.rectangle(clone1, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", clone1)

image = cv2.imread('orig.jpg')
x,y,z=np.shape(image)
clone1=cv2.resize(image,(592,700),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

clone=clone1.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click_and_crop)
while True:
    cv2.imshow("image", clone1)
    key=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("r"):
        clone1 = clone.copy()
    if key == ord("c"):
        break
if len(refPt) == 2:
    roi = clone[refPt[0][1]:refPt[1][1], refPt[0][0]:refPt[1][0]]
    roi1 = cv2.resize(roi,(y,x),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imwrite("ROI", roi1)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    print('Cropping Complete')
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Scale image to fit your screen resolution & than scale selected roi back.

Comment: Scaling cause loss of pixel values.I don't want to lose any information

Comment: You can scale it for visualization purposes... your roi may vary 1-2 pixels in size but the information will be there

Comment: either resize as suggested, or use some better gui toolkit like Qt.

Comment: i edited the question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize the image such that a ratio is obtained of the small image.For example reduce length five times and width 2 times.

```
clone1=cv2.resize(image,(y/2,x/5),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Then multiply the above constants with reference points of small image, to obtain the reference point of the original image.

```
a,b,c,d=(refPt[0][1])*5,(refPt[1][1])*5,(refPt[0][0])*2,(refPt[1][0])*2
```

Now use these reference points to obtain roi from original image

```
roi1=image[a:b, c:d]
```

Comment: It alway better to add some explanation to your answer. Without that it may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to define the parameters of the window before displaying the image?
You can try the following:

`cv2.namedWindow("image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)`

`cv2.imshow("image", clone1)`

Once you show the image, it will fit your monitor and the pixel values are the same since you did not resize the image affecting the intensity of the pixels using any interpolation.